# LinearLayout WeightSum does not work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have 6 TextViews that I'm using as buttons for my music app.  I'm using weightsum for 6 of them with `layout_weight = 1` and there is still remaining space.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6"
    tools:context="com.example.android.musicplayerapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Now playing"
        android:background="#7FB3D5"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Songs"
        android:background="#5499C7"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Artists"
        android:background="#2980B9"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Playlists"
        android:background="#2471A3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Store"
        android:background="#1F618D"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Search"
        android:background="#154360"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What exactly is wrong here?  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: By the way: `weightSum` can be omitted - it's optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the height in parent `<LinearLayout>` to cover the screen:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="6"
        tools:context="com.example.android.musicplayerapp.MainActivity">
```